# What status code we should return when request is correct but there is no data for the specific user?

Tags: .net, api, rest

I have an endpoint that return some live data for specific user (GET). And in most of the cases there is live data for most of the users, so I return the json body and `200 status code`, but in some cases the request is successful but there is just no data in Redis. What status code should I return in this case? (From my opinion is `204 NoContext`, but it cannot contain a body, so I was also thinking about `404`, but it make less sense, cause theoretically there is no error).

So what is the right status code should be returned in this case, regarding REST?

Answer (score 0):

> So what is the right status code should be returned in this case, regarding REST?

If a resource has a current representation, then responding to a request with a copy of that representation you should use status code 200.

Even when that request is "empty".

For example: consider a boring web server that maps resources to files on disk.  You send it a GET request, it finds the document that matches, that document is empty, and you get a 200 response with content length 0.

Another example: the resource is an abstraction of a list - you send a request, and at the time the list has no elements.  So the current representation is that representation derived from a list of no elements, and when you send that representation you use status code 200.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

This space intentionally left blank
```

Status codes are metadata of the [transfer of documents over a network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m8s) domain.  The semantics of the documents themselves, within their business domain, don't enter into it.